# ManualResetEvent throws NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, manualresetevent

The code throws

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the line `((ManualResetEvent)handles[i]).Set()`. I checked handles[i] has a value when I debug it. What am I doing wrong?

```
`               string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(pathFife);
                ManualResetEvent[] handles = new ManualResetEvent[fileEntries.Count()];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string fullName in fileEntries)
                {
                    handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                        var thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                AddFile(fullName, month, year, user);
                                ((ManualResetEvent)handles[i]).Set();
                            });
                        thread.Start();
                    i++;
                }
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is you have [a modified closure](http://sblakemore.com/blog/post/What-JavaScript-taught-me-about-C-Understanding-Access-to-modified-closure.aspx) on `i` where it's used inside the thread.

The value of `i` is being incremented *before* it is used in `((ManualResetEvent)handles[i]).Set();`, and at that point you haven't set the value of `handles[i]`.

This happens because the calling thread immediately goes on to the next line of code, `i++;`, before the new thread has executed `((ManualResetEvent)handles[i]).Set();`. It's a classic race condition.

To fix this problem, add the following line just before you start the thread:

`int j = i;`

And then use `j` instead of `i` in `((ManualResetEvent)handles[i]).Set();`:

```
foreach (string fullName in fileEntries)
{
    handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    int j = i;
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        AddFile(fullName, month, year, user);
        ((ManualResetEvent)handles[j]).Set();
    });
    thread.Start();
    i++;
}
```

Of course, when you run the code under the debugger the threading is completely altered and thus you didn't see the problem.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain what's wrong with this answer? The downvote is not very helpful to anyone, otherwise.